# Running Basic OpenCV program in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, anaconda

I am a beginner trying to learn opencv. I have successfully installed opencv in my ubuntu system and was trying to run a few codes from the internet and i run into this problem

```
# import the necessary packages
from __future__ import print_function
import imutils
import cv2

# load the Tetris block image, convert it to grayscale, and threshold
# the image
print("OpenCV Version: {}".format(cv2.__version__))
image = cv2.imread("tetris_blocks.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# check to see if we are using OpenCV 2.X or OpenCV 4
if imutils.is_cv2() or imutils.is_cv4():
    (cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# check to see if we are using OpenCV 3
elif imutils.is_cv3():
    (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# draw the contours on the image
cv2.drawContours(image, cnts, -1, (240, 0, 159), 3)
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The output should be an image but get the following error:

```
runfile('/home/viper_36/pythontemp/temp.py', wdir='/home/viper_36/pythontemp')
OpenCV Version: 4.0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-202e5c8bcd5b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/viper_36/pythontemp/temp.py', wdir='/home/viper_36/pythontemp')

  File "/home/viper_36/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/viper_36/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/viper_36/pythontemp/temp.py", line 11, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

Comment: check your path to the image

Comment: @HaBom Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of your error:
`(-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'`
Tells you a lot!

An 'assertion' means that the software is checking something: "if what comes next is not true: I'll throw an error."
What comes next `!_src.empty()` can be translated as: "the source image is not empty". This has to be true or the assertion will throw an error.

This all means the image path you provided is not where the image is. Make sure the tetris image is in the same folder as the one you're executing from.
Or use an absolute path. In Ubuntu that should look something like `/home/<user>/path/to/image/tetris_blocks.png`
If you ctrl-c the image in your file explorer, the absolute path will be copied!